# Multiple Record Insert in mysql using Json from an android app

Tags: android, mysql, json

i want to insert multiple record in MySQL database using Json from My Android app

if anyone have idea to insert multiple record in MySQL than tell me.

Thanks.

That's My Code:

```
String TempDial = "";
                Cursor cursord = class1.GetDial();
                if (cursord.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        TempDial = cursord.getString(1);

                        try{


                            obj_new.put("UserName", cursord.getString(1));
                            obj_new.put("Number", cursord.getString(2));
                            obj_new.put("Time", cursord.getString(3));
                            json_string = json_string + obj_new.toString() + ",";
                            } catch (Exception exc) {
                            }
                    } while (cursord.moveToNext());
                }
                if (TempDial.equals("")) {
                    // Data Not Available
                    Log.i("Temporary Data", "Not Have Temporary DialCall Data");
                } else {
                    // Get Some Data
                    json_string = json_string.substring(0, json_string.length()-1);
                    json_string += "]}";
                    Log.i("Json String", json_string);
                    Log.i("Temporary Data", "Temporary DialCall Data Available");

                    try{


                    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

                    String url = "http://api.spy.theplanetit.com/Insert_Local_Missed_Call.php";

                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json_string.getBytes("UTF8")));
                    request.setHeader("json", json_string);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                    Log.i("Data Report", response.getStatusLine().toString());
                    } catch (Exception exc) {
                    }
```

//                      class1.DeleteDial();
                    }

Comment: multiple records means,What kind of data

Comment: {"CallDat":[{"Number":"121","UserName":"hiten","Time":"Wed Apr 09 09:58:37 GMT+05:30 2014"},{"Number":"121","UserName":"hiten","Time":"Wed Apr 09 09:59:16 GMT+05:30 2014"}]}

Comment: above is my json data

Comment: you want store data in mysql from your android app,you need to create webservice method

Comment: if you have any example than please give me

Comment: where would you get it these json data

Comment: in My Web Hosting Server

Comment: and i know how to insert single data in mysql from android but no idea for multiple rows.

Comment: how would you get? USING GET method or POST method

Comment: post your code,it will help me

Comment: fine post your android code and server code,then only we have to give some sugesstion

Comment: Check my code i update my post

Comment: can you post server side code

Comment: i will post server site PHP Data

Comment: $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
   $data = json_decode($postdata, true);

   if (is_array($data['upload_fishes'])) {
      foreach ($data['upload_fishes'] as $record) {
        $fid = $record['fish_id'];
        $flat = $record['fish_lat'];
    $flon = $record['fish_lon'];

        mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO `fishes`(`fish_type_id`, `fish_lat`, `fish_lon`) VALUES ($fid, $flat, $flon)");
      }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Client side:
url should be like this

```
http://api.spy.theplanetit.com/Insert_Local_Missed_Call.php?EMP_ID=your_value&EMP_PWD=your_value
```

server side:

```
@POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/path_name")
        public Service postService(@FormParam("EMP_ID") String param1,@FormParam("EMP_PWD") String param2)
        {

            Service ud=new Service();
            String  retrievedbatch="";
            String uname="",retrievedpass="";
            try
            {
                connectionQuerry();

                PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("inser into table_name values('"+param1+"','"+param2+"'");
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("DataBase table accessed");


                con.close();
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                ud.setStatus("Failed");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
            }

            return ud;
        }
```